# How to deploy azure function app code along with ARM template in VSTS

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-rm-template

Want to know how to specify the artifact ( generated after Build process in VSTS) in ARM template so that i can deploy the function app code along with ARM template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can upload it to the azure storage blob and use msdeploy extension\resource to configure the webapp.

https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/644511d40f379ba4f1ba5ec224d5de29207b6181/ARMTemplates/WordpressTemplateWebDeployDependency.json#L58-L80

Comment: is it possible to use fileshare instead?

Comment: well, if you setup vpn between webapp and your vnet, technically you will have connectivity, but i doubt the extension can handle that